# PiGlow script in Python doesn't work

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3, led, board-leds

I just bought a PiGlow and a Pibrella, and I was curious how it worked. 
I imported a few Python scripts from [this](https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow) link, but none of the scripts does work. When I run one of the scripts, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/piglowtest2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from piglow import PiGlow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/piglow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sn3218
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sn3218.py", line 112, in <module>
    enable_leds(0b111111111111111111)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sn3218.py", line 60, in enable_leds
    [enable_mask & 0x3F, (enable_mask >> 6) & 0x3F, (enable_mask >> 12) & 0X3F])
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B.
Is there a change in the modules of Python? 
Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

This is the Pi with the Piglow:

[image: The Pi with the Piglow]

Comment: Probably you should add a photograph of your connections.

Comment: @goldilocks I did, as you can see.

Comment: Does that fit on all the way down with the case in the middle like that? Also, if that is I2C based *did you enable I2C*?  If so how?

Comment: @goldilocks yeah I did check it and it said that my IC2 is enabled.

Comment: That's not what I meant by "how".  It's your problem and it is up to you -- if you are convinced you've done everything right so you don't need to bother explaining anything other than the fact that it still doesn't work, this seems like, "Does this prove something is broken?" (no) and not "What might I have done wrong?"

Comment: @goldilocks I think you get me wrong: I'm not complaining at all. I'm just distraught what to do: I googled everything and I did all the steps, and it didn't work: I still get the same error. So I was like: maybe some people over here know how to solve the error. I just want to know what the error means and how I can fix it. So please don't get me wrong, I just don't know what to do right now.

Comment: Okay.  I apologize for seeming curt.  What I was trying to point out is, e.g., I asked "did you enable I2C? **If so how?**" and you replied, "I did check it and it said that my IC2 is enabled".   You've assumed that is a simple question and an abstract answer is sufficient, but this isn't the case.  Maybe you did it the right way.  Maybe not.  How do I know?  I guess I just take your word for it.  Or I could bug you repeatedly for information, but like I said before, it's not my problem, so there is not a huge motive for me or anyone else to keep doing that.   See the point?

Comment: As another example, while I don't have a piglow, I know how large female headers usually are, and I know how high the breakout pins in relation to the USB ports are, which are *inside* that case, whereas the piglow appears to be on top.  So unless it has unusual size headers on it to accomodate this (maybe it does), it looks at a glance like you don't have it on all the way.  But you could not bother to reply to that either.  So again, the impression is you believe you've done everything right and there's no need to demonstrate that to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the module piglow.

I suggest you google for "Raspberry Pi Python module piglow" and see if you can find the module together with installation details.

Comment: @L.Peters https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow has detailed instructions.  At which stage did you receive errors?

Comment: I downloaded the module, but then I get another error: it has got a lot of text (to much for a comment) but it's an OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Comment: That error suggests the PiGlow is not connected to the I2C bus properly.  It sounds like you have now installed the piglow module and have a new, different, problem.  A new, more targeted question may be appropriate.

Comment: I fixed the question :)